# Unable to start Hive metastore related to java exception

Tags: mysql, jdbc, hive, guava

I installed `Apache hive 3`, `Apache Hadoop 3`, `Trino` and  `Mysql (mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper)`.

When I start Hive metastore I had an exception, it blocked the start of the metastore:

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (loaded from file:/root/trino_poc/trino-server-351/etc/catalog/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/guava-19.0.jar by jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@8753f89b) called from class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration (loaded from file:/root/trino_poc/hadoop-3.2.2/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar by jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@8753f89b). 
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)
```

My solution was (I found it on github) to replace the `guava-19.0.jar` by `guava-22.0.jar`

So the metastore started well on `localhost:9083`

But the port is not in listen: `netstat -na | grep :9083` ==> nothing

in hive log I have this error:

```
   Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore_dbs?useSSL=false;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true, username = root. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------^M 
java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'useSSL' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'false;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true' is not in this set
```

So the issue is here: `'false;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true'` the `';'` is not supported in xml file because this code is exist in `hive-site.xml` and I need to properly escape the characters.

I used `'?'` instead, Hivemetastore started but port 9083 is not listen, and I got almost the same exception`'false?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true'`

I used `'&amp;'` ==> Hive metastore is not started (failed) and I got this exception:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer (file:/root/trino_poc/trino-server-351/etc/catalog/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/guava-22.0.jar) to field java.lang.Thread.inheritableThreadLocals 
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer 
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
MetaException(message:org.jets3t.service.security.ProviderCredentials)
```

If I resume:

To resolve exception to initialize Database and start hive metastore I replace the `guava-19.0.jar` by `guava-22.0.jar` but port 9083 is not listen.

Then to resolve the issue of port listening:

- I Used `'?'` instead of `';'` ==> hive metastore still started well
  but port 9083 in not listen.
- I tried using `'&amp;'` instead of    `'?'` ==> Hive metastore not
  started (failed) and I got the exception    above related to
  `guava-22.0.jar`

I hope that I was clear. Really I need to your help, because I spent a lot of hours trying to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably just remove `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` and apply the Mysql schema files on your own. Also, you already have a question mark, so adding another isn't correct - semi-colons are supposed to work and XML does allow them

Comment: @OneCricketeer what you mean by apply the Mysql schema files on your own ?
I treid by just removing createDatabaseIfNotExist=true, I got the  same exception like the mentioned one above related to adding '&amp;'

Comment: When you use the `schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema`, then it creates the databases for you. The only reason you'd need to add `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` is if you were to connect to some non-existing database, but you have `metastore_dbs` in your connection string already. Plus, I'm sure the default for `useSSL` is false, so you shouldn't need that either. Besides that, I'm looking at my working hive-site right now, and it does look like `<value>jdbc:mysql://server/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>`. Also, is the database actually running?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your answer. I deleted createDatabase because I created the DB and I kept useSSL=false even if its by default, because when I skip it return an exception that block the metastore restart.

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer , could you please take a look on my question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335035/how-using-webhdfsfilesystem